# Como transformar um UNIX timestamp em DateTime?

Tags: c#

Possuo um campo data no formato `UNIX timestamp`, e preciso transformar esse campo para um `DateTime` do C#. Como proceder?

> Exemplo de input: `1514959643539`
>
> Output desejado: `DateTime` com a informação correta de data/hora (`03/01/2018 06:07:23`)

Answer (score 1):

A classe `System.DateTimeOffset` possui métodos adequados para a manipulação de `UNIX timestamps` em um ambiente de desenvolvimento C#. Podemos fazer a transformação desejada com o código abaixo (o código foi criado para rodar no [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), a função `Dump()` (que é específica dessa aplicação) simplesmente imprime o que estiver na variável da forma mais gráfica possível:

```
void Main()
{
    var dateTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1514959643539).UtcDateTime;

    dateTime.Dump(); // 03/01/2018 06:07:23
}
```

[image: Janela de execução do aplicativo LINQPad, exibindo na parte superior o código exibido logo acima, e na parte inferior o valor "03/01/2018 06:07:23" - que é o resultado da execução do código.]